# Cannot make face, even with 4 vertices

Tags: modeling, faces

I'm modeling a chair for practice (since I'm a beginner).
I'm trying to fill in two areas. However, nothing happens when I press the F tool, even though they are 4 vertices each. [image]
[image]

When I press F for the vertices in the second image, this happens:

[image]

Why can't I fill in the vertices? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks as if you are using Skin and Subdivision modifiers to create your model .. is this right?

Comment: I am doing both, yes.

Comment: do you ask for help filling the hole with a face or to get rid of the artifact in the top left corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, the tools you have chosen are working as expected, but perhaps they are not the right tools to achieve what you want. When you hit <kbd>F</kbd>, a face *was* created between the vertices around the back of your chair. If you use the little eye icon to switch off the Skin modifier, and switch on 'Limit Selection to Visible' you'll see it there, solid shaded. *That* face is the one that a modeler using <kbd>F</kbd> would usually be interested in. (i.e the faces *between* edges, not the ones a Skin modifier has put *around* edges)

The Skin modifier rapidly creates enclosing faces to a skeleton of edges and vertices, and with it, you can quickly convert those edges into an armature to control the deformation of the faces in animation. It tries its hardest to behave well at junctions, but things made with it are usually organic, and best kept simple.

To create a chair-frame, and learn some Blender at the same time, you could perhaps try a 'Box Modeling' approach .. I've just searched on 'Blender Box Modeling' and come up with some pretty reasonable looking tutorials.

Comment: Ok, I'll avoid using Skin Modifier and look up Box Modeling. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: No need to avoid it altogether ..  it has its place! But it would certainly be worth exploring other ways of making chairs :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your selected vertex, it does not appear to be attached to the vertical edge (see how the line is dark and then fades as you move away from the vertex, but it only does this in one direction). I assume you have duplicate vertices, and thus do not have a closed loop when trying to apply the face.

Delete the duplicate vertex, recreate the edge between the vertex you have selected and the vertex below and this should solve your geometry problem.
In case you don't know, which is the duplicate select all <kbd>A</kbd> and then click `remove doubles` in the toolbox to the left (show it with <kbd>T</kbd>).

Comment: I cannot see your point. All vertices are selected. There is no case of a duplicate visible.

Comment: I agree with quiliup

Comment: @quiliup: look carefully at the picture. The upper left vertex is highlighted, but the line extending from the vertex is only highlighted for the horizontal edge. The vertical edge does not show the same highlighting/fading. This means that the vertical edge is not connected to the vertex.